# 503 Service Unavailable after hitting localhost:80, HAProxy loadbalancer running in docker container

Tags: docker, flask, haproxy, distributed-system

Facing 503 Service Unavailable after hitting localhost:80. I am using haproxy in a docker container.
my  haproxy.cfg file looks like this:

```html
global
    log /dev/log local0
    log /dev/log local1 notice
    # chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket 0.0.0.0:9000 level admin
    stats timeout 30s
    maxconn 2000
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    option httplog
    option dontlognull
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client 50000
    timeout server 50000

frontend http_front
    bind *:80
    # acl is_admin path_beg /admin
    # use_backend admin_back if is_admin
    mode http
    default_backend http_back

backend http_back
    balance roundrobin
    server webserver1 web_server_1:8083 check
    server webserver2 web_server_2:8084 check

frontend admin_front
    bind *:8081
    mode http
    acl url_admin path_beg /admin
    use_backend admin_back if url_admin

backend admin_back
    balance roundrobin
    server adminserver1 admin_server_1:8081 check
    server adminserver2 admin_server_2:8082 check
```

when i build the docker, it ran all the required container, but when i hit in localhost:80, it says 503. In docker logs, it says:
[docker log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAC4T.png)

my docker-compose.yml file:

```html
version: "3"

services:
  load_balancer:
    image: haproxy:latest
    volumes:
      - ./haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:ro
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      # - "8081:8081"
    depends_on:
      - web_server_1
      - web_server_2
      - admin_server_1
      - admin_server_2

  web_server_1:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.webserver
    ports:
      - "8083:80"

  web_server_2:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.webserver
    ports:
      - "8084:80"

  admin_server_1:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.adminserver
    ports:
      - "8081:80"

  admin_server_2:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.adminserver
    ports:
      - "8082:80"

  web_framework:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.webframework
    ports:
      - "5003:5003"
    depends_on:
      - db-mysql
    restart: always

  admin_web_framework:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.adminframework
    ports:
      - "5002:5002"
    depends_on:
      - db-mysql
    restart: always

  db-mysql:
    image: mysql
    expose:
      - "3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - ./database:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
```

Here you will find full code https://github.com/Mueem-Nahid/simple-distributed-system

After hitting localhost:80, it should forward the request to my frontend server.
[requiremnt image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q46i2.png)

Comment: Please post all code, including errors and logs as code - not images. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) for an explanation.